# Having trouble with arrays in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I'm working on a version of snake for ios, and I would like to be able to use an NSMutableArray to store the snake made of "SAFSnakePart"s.

However, whenever I set an object equal to a point in the array,and call it later, it is not usable. For example:

```
        [self addChild: [snake objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Throws the error 'Attemped to add nil node'.

Here is where I added the node to the array:

```
snakeHead = [[SAFSnakePart alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"snakeHead.png"];
[snake addObject:snakeHead];
```

How do I properly use an array and access objects in it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem is that you have not initialized the array `snake` which is why `[snake objectAtIndex:0]` is `nil`.

Before you add objects to the aray you first need to initialize it. E.g.

```
NSMutableArray *snake = [NSMutableArray new];
SAFSnakePart * snakeHead = [[SAFSnakePart alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"snakeHead.png"];
[snake addObject:snakeHead];
NSLog(@"The number of snake parts is: %d", snake.count);
```

This should in this case print "The number of snake parts is: 1".
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I forgot to initialize the array, I spent so long looking tat the code and trying to figure out the issue.

Comment: @user3422148 you might want to use the newer syntax too - might make life easier for you. e.g. NSArray *array = @[ @"some", @"array", @"elements" ]; NSString *some = array.firstObject; NSString *arrayElement = array[1];

Comment: @user3422148 Don't forget to accept the answer if this solved your problem.